# Time counter issue at Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a Discord bot which counts members voice chat time, but I got a problem. The command is separated by 2 when you're at a voice channel: "Saved time" and "Counting time". Both of the commands and client events run perfectly, but after a time (about 1 hour) **the "Counting time" of some users resets**, but I have no clue why it happens.

**What have I tried to solve my problem?**
I've tried to check Discord docs and making a thread at the awesome Stackoverflow forums.

**In order to store data**, I'm using "quickmongo" package (I used to store data in quick.db, but it seems like heroku.com host deletes all data after 1 or 2 days):